# Any know how to do this Flutter Slider? Got any existing package?

Tags: flutter, package, slider

[image]

I have been searching many websites but still cannot find a similar slider. Anyone could help me with it?

Comment: check this one https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_sliders

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.